# Как переопределить формат вывода даты в админке Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Как в джанго-админке переопределить формат вывода дат из моделей? Пытался сделать так, не получилось:

```py
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'create_time', 'get_total')

    def create_time(self, obj):
        return obj.create_time.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените имя атрибута на кастомное и получится, например:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'create_time_display', 'get_total')

    def create_time_display(self, obj):
        return obj.create_time.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

    create_time_display.short_description = '<желаемое имя>'
```

Comment: О, попробую, спасибо! Скажите, а поля модели вообще нельзя таким образом переопределить или это только времени касается?

Comment: Django резолвит каждый элемент из списка  `list_display` в определенном порядке, в первую очередь поле модели, во вторую callable объекты (в нашем случае функция) и т.д. Т.е. ваш код брал значение из поля модели и до функции дело не доходило. Подробнее тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display